# Implement increment function

Tags: haskell

I am working on this program for better understanding of haskell and state monad. I made a module Rectangle which has data type Rectangle and a function to increment the length of the rectangle. To increment the length i made a function plus. **Could there have been a better way than this plus function?** Also while incrementing i am doing addition with a new rectangle which is logically incorrect. **How to perform the increment in the correct way?**  Is there any way in which instead of giving the default width the compiler prompts the user for width?
How can i sort of extract one or more rectangle or any attribute(length or breadth) while doing stateful computation?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}
module Rectangle(Rectangle(Rectangle),GlobState(GlobState),plus,newGlobState,r1,r2,r3,incr) where

import Control.Monad.State hiding (modify)
import Data.Label (mkLabels)
import Data.Label.Pure ((:->))
import Data.Label.PureM

type Length = Int
type Width = Int

data Rectangle = Rectangle Length Width deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

data GlobState = GlobState { _r1 :: Rectangle , _r2 :: Rectangle , _r3 :: Rectangle } deriving Show
$(mkLabels [''GlobState])

plus :: Rectangle -> Rectangle -> Rectangle
plus (Rectangle x z) (Rectangle y w) = Rectangle (x+y) z

newGlobState:: GlobState
newGlobState = GlobState { _r1 = Rectangle 0 10, _r2 = Rectangle 0 10, _r3 = Rectangle 0 10}

incr :: (GlobState :-> Rectangle) -> State GlobState ()
incr x = modify x (plus (Rectangle 1 10))
```

I have made a new module for selecting one of the rectangles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}
module ChooseRect(ChooseRect(ChooseRect),makeChoice,select) where

import Rectangle
import Control.Monad.State hiding (modify)
import Data.Label (mkLabels)
import Data.Label.Pure ((:->))
import Data.Label.PureM

type Choice = Int

data ChooseRect = ChooseRect Rectangle Rectangle deriving Show

makeChoice:: Rectangle-> Rectangle->ChooseRect
makeChoice p1 p2 = ChooseRect p1 p2

select:: ChooseRect -> Choice -> Rectangle
select (ChooseRect (Rectangle x z) (Rectangle y w)) choice = if (choice==1)
                then let selectedRectangle = Rectangle x z
                in selectedRectangle
                else let selectedRectangle = Rectangle y w
                in selectedRectangle
```

But when i made changes to main module i m getting error.

```
module Main where

import Rectangle
import ChooseRect
import Control.Monad.State hiding (modify)
import Data.Label (mkLabels)
import Data.Label.Pure ((:->))
import Data.Label.PureM

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let x = flip execState newGlobState $ do
        incr r1
        incr r2
        incr r1
        incr r3
        incr r3
    let y=makeChoice r1 r2
    print y
    print x
```

The error message is

```
Couldn't match expected type `Rectangle'
            with actual type `Data.Label.Abstract.Lens
                                (~>0) GlobState Rectangle'
In the first argument of `makeChoice', namely `r1'
In the expression: makeChoice r1 r2
In an equation for `y': y = makeChoice r1 r2
```

Please explain the error and how to remove it

Comment: Is it intentional that your `incr` forces the width of the rectangle to be 10? (All your rectangles have width 10 for now, but if e.g. `r3` started as `Rectangle 0 5`, would you really want `incr` to make it `Rectangle 1 10`?)

Comment: No.. i want it to be rectangle 1 5. Thats why i asked that how can i make user to input the width

Comment: So not only is the type of your `plus` logically incorrect, it hides a bug as well.

Comment: what is the bug that it hides?

Comment: `incr` forces the width of the rectangle to be 10.

Comment: What's the error? Include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Better than your `plus` would be a `lengthenBy :: Length -> Rectangle -> Rectangle`.

   Oh, and you're using `modify` wrongly... you need to use the `modify` from Control.Monad.State *and*
   the `modify` from Data.Label.Pure.

   ```
   incr x = Control.Monad.State.modify $ Data.Label.Pure.modify x (lengthenBy 1)
   ```
2. See the functions [`getLine :: IO String`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3agetLine) (for getting a line of input) and [`read :: String -> Int`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aread) or [`reads :: String -> [(Int, String)]`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3areads) (for turning it from a `String` into an `Int`; the former is simpler to use but crashes if it can't parse the input) (and [`putStr :: String -> IO ()`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aputStr) or [`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aputStrLn) for showing a prompt).

   n.b. Do your i/o in the outermost do-block in `main`, and pass the results as extra parameters into your
   stateful computation.
3. Replace

   ```
   makeChoice r1 r2
   ```

   with

   ```
   makeChoice (get r1 x) (get r2 x)
   ```

   Look at the types:

   ```
   r1, r2 :: GlobState :-> Rectangle
   makeChoice :: Rectangle -> Rectangle -> ChooseRect
   ```

   So `r1` and `r2` are not of the right type to pass to `makeChoice`.

Comment: But if i implement plus like that it will clash with increment's definition where plus is used

Comment: The idea is that you put `lengthenBy 1` instead of `plus (Rectangle 1 10)`.

Comment: Read the error messages. Understand them. If you cannot, ask a new top-level question, and include the error messages in your new question.